# What changes are to be made in the AndroidManifest if I have many Activities in same package?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-alarms

Im using alarm intent to set an alarm

**Code :**

```
             Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM); 
              i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, meet); 
              i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour); 
              i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, min); 
              startActivity(i);
```

As i have already selected the time ,date and the message from my app i don't want to make any changes in the alarm app as this intent is fired.

I have to press the **OK** button every time i set an alarm.

here is the screenshot http://www.mediafire.com/view/jd97i9xevpid829/alam.bmp
i don't want this screen to popup, and press the ok button again and again.
what should i do>?

Comment: What error are you getting please let us know? And if possible the then please post the code of `CalendarActivity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the best answer for you >> [Start Development on Android/Training](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)